# Elevation not working on android seekbar

Tags: android, material-design, android-seekbar, android-elevation

It seems the elevation is ignored by seekbar? Any way to get it running? I already changed the background of the embedding view to a solid color, did not help.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">
        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="4dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 1- You are testing your code using a Lollipop device, right? 2- Seekbars have a shadow/glow/touch state (or make a custom one)... elevation is not needed.

Comment: 1) Yes, on Lollipop. 2) Hmm, I don't see a shadow, only the glow.

Comment: It depends on the SDK you're using... Lollipop and Material Design use a Glow for the SeekBar (Holo use it too). I think you should go for a custom SeekBar to achieve a "shadow" look.

Comment: Okay, will play around more, thank you. Question is open if anyone knows a "just set xy=true" trick. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of testing I decided to embed the SeekBar in a wrapper View and elevated the wrapper instead of the seekbar. Not as cool, but works.